# In Islam is it allowed to have images of men on ecommerce's websites?

Tags: sharia, image

I am creating website from last two year with the non living images

But now the market is changes, competition is high, and without good image my designs not sell because they not look good, I basically create shopping websites, a person with cloth add beauty in it.

I asked various buddies, they told me images are not allowed because they are cause of Budth parastish (idol worship) and I know that now days images are also main source of many sins but I am not using images of women, but of men  with clothes on and not showing his body.

Is it allowed as I am not providing a wrong thing to people which turn toward a wrong path?

Its not going to harm anybody at any point of view.

Comment: So do you really think that a **nice looking** picture of a man can increase your rizq? I don't think so. And who is this nice looking person? Is he a fully shaven guy without a beard? No dear... The rizq of Allaah will reach you even if you hide in a cave. You have only to work.